# Nested Dictionary Dataframe Error Shape of passed values is (13, 1), indices imply (13, 13)

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested, tuples

I am  working on a nested dictionary and I need help on creating the dataframe.

Python Codes:

```
authorstats= props['authorStats']
follower = props['authorStats']['followerCount']
heartcount = props['authorStats']['heartCount']
AuthorID = props['itemInfos']['authorId']
Commentcount = props['itemInfos']['commentCount']
CreateTime = props['itemInfos']['createTime']
Diggcount = props['itemInfos']['diggCount']
ID = props['itemInfos']['id']
VideoPlaycount = props['itemInfos']['playCount']
VideoSharecount = props['itemInfos']['shareCount']
VideoText = props['itemInfos']['text']
MusicAuthorName = props['musicInfos']['authorName']
MusicID = props['musicInfos']['musicId']
Musicname = props['musicInfos']['musicName']
Meta = follower,heartcount,AuthorID,Commentcount,CreateTime,Diggcount,ID,VideoPlaycount,VideoSharecount,VideoText,MusicAuthorName,MusicID,Musicname
import pandas
print(pandas.DataFrame(Meta,columns=['NumberofFollowers','HeartCount','AuthorID','NumberofComments','Create Time','Diggcount','ID','Video Play Count','Video Share Count','Video Text','Music Author Name','Music ID','Music Name']))
```

Error Message I get is

```
(2147278, '10899962', '84453035275386880', 300, '1587111974', 14089, '6816594007829859589', 91036, 29, 'I’m that friend who can’t stand still when taking photos', 'Alan Walker, Ruben', '6805465027164768258', 'Heading Home')

    File "C:/Users/abcd/PycharmProjects/Selinium/Lets start working", line 62, in <module>
        print(pandas.DataFrame(Meta,columns=['NumberofFollowers','HeartCount','AuthorID','NumberofComments','Create Time','Diggcount','ID','Video Play Count','Video Share Count','Video Text','Music Author Name','Music ID','Music Name']))
      File "C:\Users\abcd\PycharmProjects\Selinium\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 488, in __init__
        mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
      File "C:\Users\k.bengi\PycharmProjects\Selinium\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 210, in init_ndarray
        return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
      File "C:\Users\abcd\PycharmProjects\Selinium\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1664, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
        construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
      File "C:\Users\abcd\PycharmProjects\Selinium\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1694, in construction_error
        raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
    ValueError: Shape of passed values is (13, 1), indices imply (13, 13)`
```

Expected Output is a table which has columns such as 'NumberofFollowers','HeartCount','AuthorID' with the information you can see on the first line of error such as 2147278 is the Number of Followers , '10899962' is the HeartCount, '84453035275386880' is the Author ID ... )

Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the column dictionaries to DataFrames and running the following:

```
df = pandas.concat([follower,heartcount,AuthorID,Commentcount,CreateTime,Diggcount,ID,VideoPlaycount,VideoSharecount,VideoText,MusicAuthorName,MusicID,Musicname])
```

should create the DataFrame correctly, only the columns will have to be renamed:

```
df.columns=['NumberofFollowers','HeartCount','AuthorID','NumberofComments','Create Time','Diggcount','ID','Video Play Count','Video Share Count','Video Text','Music Author Name','Music ID','Music Name']
```

Comment: I am pretty new in python :) tried to used your code and get this error : cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'int'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid . How can I convert the column dictionaries into Dataframes ?

Comment: You can use ```follower = pandas.DataFrame(list(follower.items())) ``` (and respectively for the other dictionaries). This will put keys and values in separate columns, is that what you are looking for?